# Android Vector Icon - Add a border

Tags: java, android, vector, icons, android-drawable

I'm wondering if it may be possible to add a white border to a Android Vector Icon (xml format). I've tried to overlap a bigger version of the icon itself, but the result it's not as I was expecting (as you can see in the attached images).

Is there a way to modify the xml to enlarge a bit the vector itself (e.g.: a couple of pixels) and then use two different colours inside of it?

[image: Without border]

[image: Overlap vectors]

Comment: How to draw border around <clip-path> instead of <path> ?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Try adding this to your `path` in the Vector xml

```
<path ....
    android:strokeColor="#FFFFFF" android:strokeWidth="2"
```

Comment: This will work, but you must ensure `android:tint="..."` is not set in the vector i.e `<vector
    ...
    android:tint="@color/myGreen" <!--Delete this line if present-->
    ...>
    <path
        android:fillColor="@android:color/white"
        ...
        android:strokeColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:strokeWidth="0.5"
        />
</vector>`

Comment: How to draw border around <clip-path> instead of <path> ?